# Camel Transaction Configuration Issue: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: spring, transactions, apache-camel

I'm configuring JMS Transactions in Camel 2.10.4 routes. When I run my app, a `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction in progress` is thrown. From my research, I found out that this exception is thrown when no method is marked `@Transactional`. The relevant sections in my application context XML config file is shown:

```
<bean id="txMgr" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txMgr" />
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" />
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" 
   class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
   <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
   class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
   <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" 
   class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="transacted" value="true" />
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="txMgr" />
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

Besides the JMS-specific configuration, I also have JPA configuration, which is shown below:

```
<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fileRecord" />
</bean>
```

If I disable transactions, the configuration works. When I enable it, however, all the other steps succeeds except the bit where the data is to be inserted into the database (at the JPA endpoint).

Any suggestions on what I need to change or add will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Please post the code for your routes as well

Comment: you need to set transacted=false on the JmsConfig (this property tells the underlying spring DefaultMessageContainerListener to manage the transaction itself, which is exactly what you dont want to do, you want the transactionManager in charge - the java doc has a short explanation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html))